# how can i make object names include variables?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I want to create a list of objects who's names are derived from the stage of the loop it's in. This is kind of what im getting at:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    "object_"+str(i)= i+12
print(object_2)
```

But this returns the error:
                                                                                                         SyntaxError: can't assign to operator.

Would this be something that we could do? or would we not be able to call objects created in the loop from outside the loop?

Comment: Don't use the `exec` approach, though. Use a dictionary to store your names.